# Defer form processing with PHP

Tags: php

There's a lot of form processing that happens when the user hits "submit" so it takes too long before they're sent to the thank you page.

I'm trying to find a method to defer form processing. So I send them to the thank you page right away and then do all the form processing stuff after.

The only way I see of doing it now is to put all the data in $_POST (sample below) and send it with cURL. But is this the best way? Is there not a built-in PHP function for doing this?

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.example.com/form_processor.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            http_build_query(array('postvar1' => 'value1')));

// Receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: How can you send them to a thank you page if you don't know what they've entered is valid first? What's the point of the validation then?

Comment: why not just an asyncronous activity? was thinking about submitting with ajax and getting a first "thank you. we are processing your data" and then "thank you. Data processed successfully" or "Errors processing your data" (and back to the form to fix)

Comment: This doesn't gain you anything -- hitting the validation page with curl still requires you to wait for the validation page...

Comment: @j08691 oops you're right, i removed "validation" from my question. I validate on the front-end on the submit page.

Comment: @AlexHowansky yep, sorry I removed "validation" from my question. I validate on the form page, it's just form processing stuff that happens afterwards

Comment: If you want to separate the form processing from the web request then you'll need some sort of asynchronous job system. Simplest case is you submit the job to a queue and then process the queue every once in a while with a cron job.

Comment: First, let's be clear. Do you mean that you want the form processing to begin immediately or after some time following validation? If you want it to begin immediately, ajax might be suitable for that. If you want it to be after some time, setting up a cron job might be a suitable option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to tackle this is to have a queue system

- User submits form
- Posted values are saved in a DB table
- User is given the thank you page
- A cron is set up to run a PHP script
- This PHP script runs any unprocessed rows in the DB
- PHP script uses the posted values saved in the DB to process the form
- PHP updates the rows to mark them as processed

This is very scale-able and gives you a lot of control over when and how you should process the form, as well as logging and replying form processing to debug bugs.

Comment: Checked everything including Ajax, but it may still result in lost leads, so this is definitely the best way to go.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to stick with php then ajax can be a good choice. Do the processing with ajax call which is asynchronous and your page will not keep waiting until the processing finish.

For http client, you may use [guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) which is a lot easier than using curl directly.

Comment: _"your page will not keep waiting until the processing finish"_ wrong. The user will wait anyway for the ajax process to complete and cannot leave the page. The only difference is that you can provide an update about the validation process progressing. If you copy a comment as an answer at least copy it right ;-)